# Security error - Starting TomEE Plume 1.7.4

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I downloaded the newest TomEE Plume 1.7.4 Version and tried to start it from inside IntelliJ IDEA 14 with what seems to me to be a normal server setup and I get a timeout error with the following error message repeatedly printed:

Apr 11, 2016 9:20:31 AM org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon service
WARNUNG: "null OEJP/4.7" FAIL "Security error - [Ljava.net.URI; is not whitelisted as deserialisable, prevented before loading it." - Debug for StackTrace

I can start the server from normal shell, so seems related to the IDE. Anybody has any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Newer versions of TomEE require configuring of whitelisting and blacklisting for Ejbd transport, which is covered here:

http://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html

conf/system.properties has the blacklist enabled by default

```
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = *
```

... however it can be disabled by setting this value to "-"

```
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
```

Comment: holy moly, that was it!

Comment: Kindly note there are some default blacklist values from 1.7.3 which the link goes into detail for, as this list was previously uneditable. If you just disable the blacklist you will be less secure than you started... Definitely go through that page to see what the old behavior was if that is desired behavior.